# What is the history of the charbhuja temple in Garhbor village in the Kumbhalgarh, Rajasthan

Tags: vishnu

On our visit to kumbhalgarh, Rajasthan we visit Garhbor village near the town, there is popular temple called charbhuja ji temple,the temple is believed to be built by Pandavas and the deity was carved by vishwakarma  on the order of Krishna himself
My question to related to this temple are
1 do any scriptures talk about this shrine?

Answer (score 0):

**History:**

The Charbhuja Temple, also known as the Chaturbhuja Temple, is a prominent Hindu temple located in the village of Garhbor near Kumbhalgarh in the state of Rajasthan, India. The temple is dedicated to Lord Vishnu, who is depicted in his Chaturbhuja form, meaning "four-armed."

The history of the Charbhuja Temple dates back several centuries, and it has significant religious and cultural importance in the region. While exact historical records may be limited, the temple's origin is believed to have connections to the 15th century.

According to local legends and traditions, the temple was constructed during the reign of Maharana Kumbha (1433–1468 AD), who was a prominent ruler of the Mewar kingdom and known for his patronage of arts and religion. It is said that Maharana Kumbha had a divine vision or dream in which Lord Vishnu appeared to him and instructed him to build a temple at the specific location in Garhbor.

The temple's architecture showcases the intricate craftsmanship of the Mewar region, characterized by beautiful carvings and sculptures. The main deity, Lord Vishnu, is enshrined in a four-armed form, holding a conch (shankha), discus (chakra), mace (gada), and lotus (padma) in his hands.

Over the centuries, the Charbhuja Temple has undergone renovations and additions, reflecting the cultural and artistic influences of different periods. The temple complex has various structures and courtyards, providing space for devotees to offer prayers and participate in religious ceremonies.

The Charbhuja Temple is an essential pilgrimage site for devotees of Lord Vishnu, attracting thousands of visitors, especially during festivals and religious occasions. The temple's significance extends beyond Rajasthan, drawing devotees from different parts of India.

**I couldn't found any sanskrit verses in scriptures about this temple.**

Comment: What's your source for this?

Comment: I don't use any specific or particular source to write answer.

Comment: Sources are required. See [this meta post](https://hinduism.meta.stackexchange.com/questions/786/can-we-revisit-the-sources-required-rule).